# Bring a div to forward

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This is my code below. When I resize the size of my window and navbar collapse. On dropdown of the menu, the contents appeared to be below carousel. How do I bring it to forward? here is my code:
html:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>APT - Aviation | Travel | Hospitality</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="bootstrap/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">  

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>  

              <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
          <div class="container">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-brand-centered">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </button>
              <div class="navbar-brand navbar-brand-centered">
                  <img src="images/apt-logo.gif">
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-brand-centered">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="dropdown">
                  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Academy<span class="caret"></span></a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Training programs</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">APT - 360 training</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Admission<span class="caret"></span></a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Admission guide</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#" id="apply">Apply now</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                 <li class="dropdown">
                  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Placement<span class="caret"></span></a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Companies</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Highlights</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">About<span class="caret"></span></a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Our story</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Training Methadology</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>  
                  </ul>
                </li>        
              </ul>
            </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
          </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
        </nav>
      <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <!-- Indicators -->
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
      </ol>

      <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
      <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">

        <div class="item active">
          <img src="http://www.skoda-auto.co.in/models/new-skoda-rapid/PublishingImages/Overview/Top/overview-top_New2.jpg" alt="Chania" width="100%" height="100%">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h3>Chania</h3>
            <p>The atmosphere in Chania has a touch of Florence and Venice.</p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="item">
          <img src="http://www.skoda-auto.co.in/models/new-skoda-rapid/PublishingImages/Overview/Top/overview-top_New2.jpg" alt="Chania" width="100%" height="100%">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h3>Chania</h3>
            <p>The atmosphere in Chania has a touch of Florence and Venice.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="http://www.skoda-auto.co.in/models/new-skoda-rapid/PublishingImages/Overview/Top/overview-top_New2.jpg" alt="Chania" width="100%" height="100%">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h3>Chania</h3>
            <p>The atmosphere in Chania has a touch of Florence and Venice.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="http://www.skoda-auto.co.in/models/new-skoda-rapid/PublishingImages/Overview/Top/overview-top_New2.jpg" alt="Chania" width="100%" height="100%">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h3>Chania</h3>
            <p>The atmosphere in Chania has a touch of Florence and Venice.</p>
          </div>
        </div>



      </div>

      <!-- Left and right controls -->
      <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
    </div>

    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

and css:

```
    body{
    background: #f8f8f8;
}
.navbar-brand-centered {
        position: absolute;
        left: 50%;
        display: block;
        width: 160px;
        text-align: center;
        background-color: transparent;
}
.navbar>.container .navbar-brand-centered, 
.navbar>.container-fluid .navbar-brand-centered {
        margin-left: -80px;
}
nav{
    height: 100px;
}
.navbar{
    border-bottom: none;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px){
    .navbar-brand-centered {
        left: 30%;    
    }
}
.navbar-header button{
    margin-top: 50px;
}
.nav{
    margin-top: 25px;
}
#apply{
    padding-left: 19px;
    font-weight: 600;
    color:#419044;
}
#apply:hover{
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't look to long at your code but I did not see a z-index attribute anywhere.  Did you try that? Place z-index: 1 in the css class you want to be on top.